# Spring caching - auto update cached setter

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I am really new to spring caching.

I saw that spring caching annotations are based mostly on annotating methods.

My question is if i have a dao class that has the following method:

```
 public User getUserById(long id);
```

And lets say i cache this method.

and have another dao method (with no annotation) like:

```
 public void updateUser(User u);
```

Now imagine this scenario:

1) someone invokes the getUserById(user1Id); //(cache of size 1 now has user1)

2) someone else invokes the updateUser(User1) ; // lets say a simple name change

3) someone else invokes the getUserById(user1Id);

My question :

Assuming no other actions were taken,  Will the 3rd invocation receives a deprecated data? (with the old name)?

If so , how to solve this simple use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the third invocation will return a stale data.

To overcome this, you should trigger a cache eviction after the update operation, by annotating your update method with a `@CacheEvict` annotation:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "users", key = "#user.id")
void updateUser(User user) {
    ...
}
```

Where `value = "users"` is the same cache name you had used for `getUserById()` method, and `User` class has an `id` property of type Long (which is used as the users cache key)

Answer (score 1):

You need to **remove the stale items** from cache. The Spring framework helps with several caching related annotations (you could annotate the update-method with `@CacheEvict` for example). Spring has a good [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) on caching by the way.